# Add to cart with custom data from an url using GET method in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, orders

In Woocommerce, I am adding products to cart using the GET method from an URL like:

```
http://example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=10
```

Now I would like to be able adding at the same time **some custom data** as a product note like:

```
 http://example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=10&note=hinote
```

And then saving that "hinote" value as the cart item data. Once oder is placed, I would like to save that "hinote" in order item data and display it as custom order item data everywhere.

Is that possible?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes that is possible and quiet simple… Try the following code:

```
// Add custom note as custom cart item data
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'get_custom_product_note', 30, 2 );
function get_custom_product_note( $cart_item_data, $product_id ){
    if ( isset($_GET['note']) && ! empty($_GET['note']) ) {
        $cart_item_data['custom_note'] = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['note'] );
        $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5( microtime().rand() );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}


// Display note in cart and checkout pages as cart item data - Optional
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_item_data', 10, 2 );
function display_custom_item_data( $cart_item_data, $cart_item ) {
    if ( isset( $cart_item['custom_note'] ) ){
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => "Note",
            'value' =>   $cart_item['custom_note'],
        );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Save and display product note in orders and email notifications (everywhere)
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'add_custom_note_order_item_meta', 20, 4 );
function add_custom_note_order_item_meta( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if ( isset( $values['custom_note'] ) ){
        $item->update_meta_data( 'Note',  $values['custom_note'] );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Confirming this works in 2022.  As always, @LoicTheAztec comes through.  I coupled this method with the technique on this page (https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-set-override-product-price-programmatically/) to dynamically change the product price in the cart by passing a numeric field as the note value and using that to set the price.