# Woocommerce: Add to cart via URL with custom price and parts information

Tags: ajax, woocommerce, cart

I am making a PC build website along with a Woocommerce shop. The PC build wizard is a project different from Woocommerce. So, this is what I am trying to achieve. Once the person has customised their build on the wizard, they are sent to a final page with the details of the components chosen, prices and the total price.

Now, I have placed an Add to Cart button on the final page, which should add the product with the total price and the name of specific parts chosen to the cart. I'd love it to show as a single product - "Gaming PC" with the part details and final price in the cart.

BTW, if I do add a link with the option of custom pricing as an argument, there's always a risk of the customer changing it to a value of his liking and checking out.

Is this achievable? If yes, how?

**Alternatives I thought of**

1. Add product id of each part specifically in the external website and add single "add to cart link" to add each of them in a single go. This could cause trouble since I can't provide individual parts for the same price that I sell it as part of the Gaming PC bundle.
2. Add product id of each part specifically in the external website and add single "add to cart link" to add each of them in a single go along with a coupon code for price reduction which will be calculated on the external website itself. This again is troublesome, as members might just take a few items out of it and continue checkout.

Comment: In WooCommerce core, there is the possibility to [Group products](https://woo.com/document/group-bundle-products-woocommerce/#:~:text=Grouped%20Products%20lets%20you%20add,different%20pages%20to%20do%20so.) together. This product type is more about product display and allows the customer to add range of products to their cart. It does not involve any different purchase rules. For that you could look into the possibility of bundling products. I know WooCommerce offers a [paid plugin](https://woo.com/products/product-bundles/).

Comment: @Richard I ended up using the solutions provided in these two questions to get what I want - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63996480/set-a-custom-add-to-cart-price-via-the-url-get-in-woocommerce & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51915032/add-to-cart-with-custom-data-from-an-url-using-get-method-in-woocommerce-3

Thanks for the suggestion of Grouped products.